# Indian currency symbol not show when convert html2pdf in php

Tags: php, html, pdf, yii

In my HTML report i used Indian new currency(₹) symbol. When I convert HTML report to PDF using html2pdf extension, all currency symbol change to question mark symbol. How can I prevent this from happening?

In HTML:
[image]

After convert to pdf:
In PDF:
[image]

Comment: did you find any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
include("../mpdf.php");
$mpdf=new mPDF('');
$mpdf->WriteHTML('<div style="font-family:dejavusanscondensed">&#x20b9;</div>');
$mpdf->Output();
exit;
?>
```

for reference use the link below

[How to print Indian Rupee(₹) symbol in pdf using html?](http://www.mpdf1.com/forum/discussion/1644/how-to-print-indian-rupee-symbol-in-pdf-using-html/p1)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I posted my problem with image, please see that.