# How to show arabic and english text in same line in html2pdf

Tags: php, internationalization, pdf-generation, arabic, html2pdf

I need to write a tabular text in pdf using html2pdf like that

```
<div><span> - English Translation 1 :   </span><span> :      Arabic Translation 1</span></div> 
<div><span> - English Translation 2:   </span><span> :      Arabic Translation 2</span></div> 
<div><span> - English Translation 3:   </span><span> :      Arabic Translation 3</span></div>
```

I get an example from https://github.com/iafan/html2pdf/blob/master/_tcpdf_5.9.206/examples/example_018.php But that seems work for page wise page.

I did following code so far.

```
$finder = new Zend_Dom_Query($htmlContent);
$classname = "intl-text";
$nodes = $finder->query("*[class~=\"$classname\"]");

foreach($nodes as $node) {
    foreach($features as $feature) {
        $engText = $feature->getEnglishText();
        $arbText = $feature->getArabicText();

        $div = $dom->createElement("div");

        $span = $dom->createElement("span");
        $span->nodeValue = "- ".$engText;
        $div->appendChild($span);
        $span = $dom->createElement("span");
        $span->setAttribute("style", "direction: rtl;");
        //$span->setAttribute("dir", "rtl");
        $span->nodeValue = ":   ".$arbText;
        $div->appendChild($span);

        //$div->nodeValue = "- ".$engText.":   ".$arbText;

        $node->appendChild($div);
    }
}   

$content = $nodes->getDocument()->saveHTML();

$html2pdf->writeHTML($content, false);
$html2pdf->Output(__DIR__.'Output.pdf', 'F');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more searching I get fix through the following change.

```
$span->setAttribute("style", "direction: rtl;display: inline-block;font-family:dejavusanscondensed;");
```

Font Family in css done the trick and text is now showing in arabic in pdf. However it is not right aligned. But I suspect that may require some html fixing.

From : [Indian currency symbol not show when convert html2pdf in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886668/indian-currency-symbol-not-show-when-convert-html2pdf-in-php) .